# Complex editing with ffmpeg - Adobe Premiere replacement

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I do a lot of video editing in Adobe Premiere and a certain branch of the work is very repetitive, so I was thinking maybe I could make a script to automate the process with ffmpeg.

After tying myself up in knots trying to get it to work I am getting nowhere and I could really use some pointers.

I will attempt to describe my ultimate goal with a kind of pseudo-description:

```
                   [<------v:watermark.png----->]
    [/v:clip1.mp4\][/v:clip2.mp4\][/v:clip3.mp4\][/v:clip4.mp4\]
    [<a:clip1.mp4>][------a:soundtrack.mp3----->][<a:clip4.mp4>]
```

Where / & \ are fade in and out (to black), and < is a cross-dissolve.

Or, to describe it textually:
A bunch of video clips that each fade in from black, then fade out to black before the next clip plays. Audio from first and last clip is present (intro and outro), audio from other clips removed and replaced with an mp3 file which fades out (and is trimmed to fit if required) before the last clip plays. A watermark displayed over the whole thing except the first and last clip, preferably using what Photoshop (and ImageMagick too, I think) calls 'overlay' mode, though I could live with a plain blend.

Now that I wrote a description it does seem rather complex, and I don't feel ashamed that I can't get anywhere near it by myself. In Premiere it's just a muscle memory process that is tedious and time consuming.

I'm not asking anybody to write this for me, I would be happy with some pointers!

Points of information:

- The clips are in a variety of containers and codecs.
- The clips are all the exact same resolution (1920x1080).
- The framerate of clips does vary, but only between 29.97 and 30 FPS or so, I'm happy railroading it all to 30FPS.
- I seek avoiding multiple encode passes.

Answer (score 0):

## Let's revive this forgotten thread!

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -i clip1.mp4 -i clip2.mp4 -i clip3.mp4 -i clip4.mp4 -i watermark.png -i soundtrack.mp3 -filter_complex "\
[1:v][2:v]concat[12clips];\
[12clips][4:v]overlay[12overlay];
[0:v][12overlay][3:v]concat=n=3[video];\
[0:a][5:a][3:a]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[audio]\
" -map "[video]" -map "[audio]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac output.mp4
```

#### Join the middle clips before applying watermark

```
[1:v][2:v]concat[12clips]
```

#### Apply the water mark to the middle clips

(you might want to tweak the overlay filter to obtain optimal results with your watermark)

```
[12clips][4:v]overlay[12overlay]
```

before applying the watermark you might have to use format=yuva420p to include the alpha channel while overlaying

```
[4:v]format=yuva420[wateralpha];[12clips][wateralpha]overlay[12overlay]
```

#### Join all the video clips

```
[0:v][12overlay][3:v]concat=n=3[video];
```

#### Join all the audio clips

```
[0:a][5:a][3:a]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[audio]
```

#### Map the streams and encode!

```
 -map "[video]" -map "[audio]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac output.mp4
```

Let me know how it went!